# Getting error in Spark Structured Streaming for using from_json function

Tags: scala, apache-spark, spark-structured-streaming

I am reading the data from Kafka and my spark code contains the following code:

```
val hiveDf = parsedDf
    .select(from_json(col("value"), schema).as("value"))
    .selectExpr("value.*")
```

When I am running it from IntelliJ it is working but when I am running it as a jar it is throwing following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.spark.sql.functions$.from_json(Lorg/apache/spark/sql/Column;Lorg/apache/spark/sql/types/StructType;)Lorg/apache/spark/sql/Column;
```

my spark-submit command looks like this:

```
C:\spark>.\bin\spark-submit --jars C:\Users\namaagarwal\Desktop\Spark_FI\spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.11-2.1.0.cloudera1.jar --class ClickStream C:\Users\namaagarwal\Desktop\Spark_FI\SparkStreamingFI\target\scala-2.11\sparkstreamingfi_2.11-0.1.jar
```

Comment: `from_json` was added in spark 2.1.0. Maybe your `spark-submit` in `c:\spark` is older distribution?

Comment: Yes you are right. I was using Spark 2.0. Now I got it working.

Comment: @NamanAgarwal can you please share the details how did you got it working. I am facing same issue.

Comment: @RahulJain from_json was enabled from spark 2.1. Check your spark version and change it to Spark 2.1 or greater.